# enabling nested transaction in eclipselink jpa

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

We use eclipse link for JPA and I have a requirement to commit a nested transaction which is wrapped in larger/parent transaction scope.

I have requirement to commit the a specific entityobject every minutes, which runs as part of a bigger transaction, which can take longer time to finish. Because of the parent transaction scope, the subset operation is not getting committed every minutes. It only gets committed as part of the larger/parent transaction.

Is there a way to commit nested transaction independently of its parent transaction scope? 
My project wont support spring or any other JPA framework. It supports only eclipse-link JPA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your JPA configuration? and where is your JTA transaction?

Comment: on some databases definitely impossible. On Misrosoft SQL maybe eclipselink can do such scenario. Be ready to few nuances